# How to get 1:n relation in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes (database tables) `Expense` and `Country`.

The `Expense` class has a `CountryId` column.

Now I want to retrieve all `Expense` entries plus related `countryName`.

How do I get related country name of each expense?

Appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: If you want advice, follow an EF tutorial, try, and ask when in doubt. By seeing your question it looks like "I have no idea of EF", not even "I know very little about EF and I have many doubts". There are interesting tutorials by MS.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually it is my first Entity Framework project and I have searched on Google.

Comment: The MS tutorials are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907 Seriously, don't try to use EF with a cookbook. I know we are usualy short of time, but your mistakes of today will spoil your time tomorrow. You should start from the beginning, but here you have info on relations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add virtual property to Expense class:

```
public class Expense {
    ...
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")] 
    public virtual Country Country {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then country name can be accessed via somexpense.Country.Name or whatever the name property is.